# Why is Image in a flutter app importing from painting.dart and not images.dart?

Tags: android, flutter

I have created several apps that use the Image object (from the image.dart library).
However today I created one app from scratch (using the Android Studio template) and when I add an Image object it gets imported from painting.dart, and things like Image.memory() don't work anymore.Never had this problem before.
This is the class and the offending member. It could not be simpler.

```
import 'dart:ui';

class ProdutoDoCardapio {
  int codigo;
   int codprod;
   String descricao;
   String descrcurta;
   String descrlonga;
   int destaque;
   String obs;
   double preco;
   String unidade;
   String foto;
  int qtde = 0 ;
  Image imagedata;

}
```

So my question is: do I have to configure something in some file I am missing to make flutter (or dart) use the correct library in my context?
I tried

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';
```

in the class file, but flutter says this url does not exist, although it is mentioned in many exemples online.

So, any help will be welcome.

Comment: Please post your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your time, @VictorEronmosele, but it was really a beginner's mistake, nothing complicated, as you can see in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I accepted Flutter's suggestion to import dart.ui, but the correct import is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

So the problem is solved.